# css не работает :has() в Mozilla

Tags: css, firefox

Надо стилизовать `radio`, вставил изображение в `label`, используя `:has()` и псевдо, но в итоге увидел, что *Firefox Mozilla*(последняя версия) ее не поддерживает.

```css
.mozilla label:has(#field_657b32a1017f4):before {
  content:url('https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-48/free-small-diamond-geometric-blue-38006.png');
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="mozilla">
<label><input type="radio" id="field_657b32a1017f4" name="test-radio" value="Indistrial" checked="checked">test</label>
</div>
```

Можно не меняя код и не используя js обратиться к родителю на css кроссбраузерно?

Comment: `обратиться к родителю на css кроссбраузерно?` - пока, никак. Нужно либо менять вашу структуру HTML и подход к стилизации, либо использовать JavaScript.

Comment: 19 декабря 2023 года выходит Firefox 121, там будет поддержка `:has`

Comment: Я написал ответ, как реализовать вашу задачу визуально. Но может быть вам и не нужно проверять наличие id у элемента?

Answer (score 0):

если с доступом к чему то кроме css проблемки, можно попытаться сам инпут и кастомизировать, выбросив его стоковый appearance.

вам ведь его родитель только для этого и нужен, верно?

---

назвать это прям хорошей практикой конечно не могу, но...

его поддержка уж явно получше чем у `:has`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

```css
.a{
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-ms-appearance: none;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 0 100% 100% 100%;
border: 15px dashed green;
transition: all .5s ease-out;
display: list-item;
list-style: 'вжух' inside;
text-align: center;
}
.a::marker{
font-size: 50px;
color: lime;
}
.a:before{
display: block;
content: 'в FF 91 это работает и без префиксов';
font-size: 20px;
color: orange;
}
.a:checked{
border-radius: 100% 10% 100% 10%;
}
[type=checkbox]{
background: linear-gradient(to top, darkred, darkblue);}
[type=radio]{
background: linear-gradient(to top, gray, brown);}
```

```html
<input class='a' type='checkbox'>
<input class='a' type='radio' name='x'>
<input class='a' type='radio' name='x'>
<input class='a' type='radio' name='x'>
```

Comment: эм, человек же написал CSS селектор, который при наличии элемента #field_657b32a1017f4 применяет стили к before элементу тега label. Он не написал ни слова про :checked. Ваш код не делает того, что делает код автора

Comment: вот первые слова вопроса `Надо стилизовать` **`radio`** остальное лишь инструмент для достижения этого и соответственно заменяемо, лишь бы оставаться в рамках css. кстати спасибо, что обратили внимание... чот вместо радио чекбокс воткнул...))

Comment: Если надо стилизовать просто radio, то, конечно, непонятно, зачем наличие input'а с определённым id

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос: `Можно не меняя код и не используя js обратиться к родителю на css кроссбраузерно?`
Ответ: на текущий момент (19 декабря 2023 года) **нельзя**, хоть и сегодня Firefox обновится и там будет работать `:has`, это не означает, что все пользователи Firefox решат с обновлённым браузером заходить на ваш сайт. Можно только придумать ухищрения, которые я предлагаю ниже

Реализация на чистом CSS: элементы визуально расположены также, как у вас. в HTML они расположены не также, их очередность(визуальная) изменена с помощью сетки `grid`, свойства `grid-template-areas`

Картинка по умолчанию скрыта:

```css
.mozilla__img {
  display: none;
}
```

при наличии элемента `#field_657b32a1017f4` обратиться к соседу ниже (`+`), который должен являться `.mozilla__img`

```css
#field_657b32a1017f4 + .mozilla__img {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.mozilla__label {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "img img" 
                       "input input-text";
}

.mozilla__img {
  grid-area: img;
  display: none;
}

.mozilla__img::before {
  content :url('https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-48/free-small-diamond-geometric-blue-38006.png');
  display: block;
}

.mozilla__input-text{
  grid-area: input-text;
}

.mozilla__input {
  grid-area: input
}

#field_657b32a1017f4 + .mozilla__img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mozilla">
  <label class="mozilla__label">
    <span class="mozilla__input-text">test</span>
    <input class="mozilla__input" type="radio" id="field_657b32a1017f4" name="test-radio" value="Indistrial" checked="checked">
    <div class="mozilla__img">
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```